# How to get Request first value and split the whole string in exactly 2 parts?

Tags: php, json

I have a Request in laravel where I pass a json object. The json is the following: `{ "firstname": "michael" }`.

I am writing a dynamic search function and I want to store the data as 2 different values the "firstname" and the "michael". How can I do that in php ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php would be a good start

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = json_decode('{"firstname":"michael"}', TRUE);

foreach ($array as $first => $second){
    echo "first: {$first}\nsecond: {$second}";
}
```

Return:

```
first: firstname
second: michael
```

Comment: the provblem is that i dont know if the my GUI gives me firstname or lastname ... i am writing a dynamic search function so i wanna get every time the key value and the value in 2 parts to pass them to my search function ...